# How to filter type values in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Tried to filter type in mongoDB where `type = "vod","playlist","series"`

I'm trying like this .

```
let filter = {
  type : "vod"&"playlist"&"series"
}
let video = await Video.find(filter);
```

It's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter it on an `$or` operator like this:

```js
async function getVideosFiltered(req, res) {
  try {
    const videosFiltered = await Video.find({
      $or: [{ type: "vod" }, { type: "playlist" }, { type: "series" }],
    });
    return res.status(200).send({
      data: videosFiltered,
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Error from server", success: false });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming you want to filter based on the types you have. so you can use an operator available in MongoDB that is `$in`
you can just pass an object in the find

```
let types = ["vod","playlist","series"];
await Video.find({type:{$in:types}});
```

I have not tested it. Check it and reply, should work.
mongodb docs link ->
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: can you share what error are you getting on this query I ran on my database It's working fine? Would be helpful